# How to enable Google Plus button without enabling 3rd party cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, google-plus

When I try to click on the Google `g+` button (found on some sites alongside Facebook `Like` and Twitter `Share` et.al), I am told that this requires 3rd party cookies, which I always disable in all browsers I use; this is non-negotiable.

What do I put into the `hostname pattern` in the `cookie and site data exceptions` in Google Chrome to enable `g+1` without enabling anything else?

Temporarily enabling 3rd party cookies just to click on `g+1` is, obviously, not a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and found on a google forum that you needed to enable `plus.google.com`, `plusone.google.com` and `google.com`.

This worked for me.  I was still getting issues with the site not being publicly available, watch for that.

In Chrome I ended up adding the URL pattern :

```
[*.]google.com
```

Comment: I don't trust `google` enough to enable all their cookies; OTOH, they might be using this cookie scheme specifically to make sure that if I want to enable g+, I have to enable all their cookies.

Comment: Could be.  Wether we trust of not.  I think at the end of the day it's up to the users using the website.  You could very well have the +1 not working on your browser, but if it's working for your users, then everyone's happy.  Anywho.  Google will own the world pretty soon anyways.